# How to turn off formatting for numeric expressions? Visual Studio C++

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I've done it a thousand jillion times. I write a numeric expression in C++. It is a thing of beauty and a joy to all who behold. Maybe it's something like this:

```
 y[N/2 + k] = stuff; // Beauty, eh?
```

As I type the final semicolon, Visual Studio says, "No, no, no. You have it all wrong. It should look like *this:*"

```
y[N / 2 + k] = stuff; // Have it my way, human!
```

"You need *more spaces!*"

On that we disagree.

I go back and edit out the gratuitous spaces - sometimes a lot of them. Hrrrmph.  Is there no option to make it not do that? I have searched in vain. I have also searched in the options-menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2013 (and perhaps others):

Select TOOLS-> Options-> Text Editor-> C/C++ -> Formatting. There you will find a checkbox to disable the automatic formatting of statements after typing a semicolon.

For finer granularity, you can drill into Formatting to the Spacing tab and really get specific.

TOOLS-> Options-> Text Editor-> C/C++ -> Formatting-> Spacing -> Binary operators// Select: *Don't change spaces around binary operators*